# How would I display both first name and Surname on my html spring boot jdbc

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am using a select statement in my jdbcTemplate. I am trying to select firstname and surname and display them on the html page however I am getting errors.The error code I am getting on the HTml page is **"Incorrect column count: expected 1, actual 2"**

```
    public List<String> getAllUserNames() {
    List<String> usernameList = new ArrayList<>();
    usernameList.addAll(jdbcTemplate.queryForList("SELECT FirstName,Surname from paitents",String.class));
    return usernameList;
}
```

Html file

```html
<tr th:each="user : ${users}">
    <a href="#" th:text="${user} + ${user.Surname}" ></a> <br>
<!--    <td th:text="${user}"> </td> <br>-->

</tr>
</body>
```

Comment: When I do a select statement for only the firstname or only 1 column it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are constructing a **String** List and then trying to insert a complex object type into the list. You have two solutions here; first one is to use a complex type and use that list. An example might be as follows:

```
public List<User> findAllUsers() {
   String sql = "SELECT FirstName,Surname from paitents";
   return jdbcTemplate.query(sql,
                (rs, rowNum) ->
                        new User(
                                rs.getString("FirstName"),
                                rs.getString("Surname")
                        ));
}
```

And then in thymeleaf code:

```
<tr th:each="user : ${users}">
    <a href="#" th:text="${user.FirstName} + ${user.Surname}" ></a> <br>
</tr>
```

Another solution is a quick fix and you can use a sql trick to do that:

```
public List<String> getAllUserNames() {
    List<String> usernameList = new ArrayList<>();
    usernameList.addAll(jdbcTemplate.queryForList("SELECT CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', Surname) AS FullName from paitents",String.class));
    return usernameList;
}
```

You should put this List in a model at your controller method:

```
model.addAttribute("fullNameList", usernameList);
```

And then in view layer:

```
<tr th:each="fullName : ${fullNameList}">
    <a href="#" th:text="${fullName}" ></a> <br>
</tr>
```

Comment: When trying to implement the first solution I am getting 'null' for every single value. What should the user model have? In mine I have FirstName , Surname , the constructer , getters and setters and toString

Comment: You should hava a User constructor with two arguments (FirstName and Surname); thats it.

Comment: When trying to get an int value for example PatientNumber do I do rs.getInt("PatientNumber") ?

Comment: If your database column type is integer then yes you should do rs.getInt("ColumnNam")